# I want to plot an intersection point from 2 street names on a map

Tags: curated-data, geography, intersection

Say, I want to plot the point of 5th ave & E 79th ave in NYC on a map, how should I do it with mathematica?

Also, say I have a street, say 5th ave in NYC, can I ask to give me all the intersections in a list with the street names that meet at those intersections?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: `WolframAlpha["5th avenue cross streets"]`

Comment: Thanks,  that gives good answer for cross streets.

Comment: Also, can someone help me on the first question, given 2 street names, Can I plot the point of their intersection on a map?

Comment: One way is to get a Google Geocoding API Key and use `res = Import["https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=5th+Ave+and+79th+St,+New+York,+NY&key=..._YourKeyHere_...", "JSON"]; Fold[ReplaceAll[#2, #1] &, res, {"results", "geometry", "location"}]`....But maybe there's a built-in way.